# Rename Directory using PHP Script

Tags: php, batch-rename

I have a directory containing folders like

> baseurl/2-435435435_323423/
>   
> baseurl/5_435435435_32423/ 
>   
> baseurl/3_543543543_2342342/

Now i want to rename all the folders from their original name to new name i.e. truncate last part separated by '_'. new names would be

> baseurl/2-435435435/
>   
> baseurl/5_435435435/
>   
> baseurl/3_543543543/

```
$path_from = 'E:/documents/';
if(file_exists($path_from)){
    $files = scandir($path_from);
    foreach($files as $key1 => $file) {
        $newName = ? // I need this
        rename($path_from.$file,$path_from.$newName);
    }
}
```

Or Let me know if there is anyway in windows to rename batch without any script.

Comment: you can use bulk rename utility tool in windows. [Link to tool](http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Main_Intro.php)

Comment: Check what answer you accept and is it work correct or not.

Comment: @FrayneKonok you were right. but for my case I had only one '_'. It wasn't a big deal. Though no answer is complete but I solved my problem.  and I thought there should be correct answer.

Comment: Take a look at your given data, there are mixing of `-` and `_`.

Comment: @FrayneKonok yeah, you are right. I removed correct answer flag.

Comment: See my last answer and my comment to Frayne

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you mention for getting only `$newName`, Just use `substr` and `strrpos`.

`strrpos` - Find the numeric position of the last occurrence of a string

```
$str = 'baseurl/3_543543543_2342342/';

$pos = strrpos($str, "_");
if ($pos === false){
    //do nothing
}else
    $str = substr($str, 0, $pos)."/";

echo $newName = $str; //baseurl/3_543543543/
```

Comment: Thank you :) Finally you figured it out. what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [strstr](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php)

```
$path_from = 'E:/documents/';
    if(file_exists($path_from)){
        $files = scandir($path_from);
        foreach($files as $key1 => $file) {
            $newName = strstr($file, '_', true);
            rename($path_from.$file,$path_from.$newName);
        }
    }
```

e.g.

```
$str = 'baseurl/2-435435435_323423/';
    $imagePreFix = strstr($str, '_', true);
    echo $imagePreFix;
```

OUTPUT:

> baseurl/2-435435435

Comment: interesting, I didn't know the last parameter: bool $before_needle = false   :)

Comment: that parameter was added in PHP 5.3

Comment: @Suyog, Is this return what OP want? What is the output of `$newName = strstr($file, '_', true);`??

Comment: @FrayneKonok plz see the example. I have tried it on my system.

Comment: Make a test with `baseurl/5_435435435_32423/` as the `$file`.

Comment: I mark you downvote and now remove it, make your answer correct, The OP need to get downvote.

Comment: It is fine if we only have one "_" as in my case. Frayne have point that it is not generalize.

Answer (score 0):

```
$newName = substr($file, 0, strrpos($file, '_'));
```

Comment: please update strpos to strrpos as i needed to truncate after last '_'

Comment: you should use some more description about your answer.

Comment: Sorry, was a typo in fact